# How to get the parent controller for a custom TextField

Tags: ember.js

I have a simple controller

```
App.UploadController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  toUpload: Ember.A([])
});
```

I have a template backing this w/ a custom text field

```
<div>
{{view App.UploadFileView name="file" contentBinding="content"}}
</div>
```

My custom text field in JS is below. The problem I'm having is that in the change event, I need to push an object into the parent controllers "toUpload" array but when I do a get on the parentView.controller it's undefined. How can I get the parent in this scenario?

```
App.UploadFileView = Ember.TextField.extend({
  type: 'file'
  change: function() {
    var foo = Ember.Object.create();
    this.get('parentView.controller').get('toUpload').pushObject(foo);
  }
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't the controller in this scope be the parent view's controller (I didn't test this, I swear I have some code that looks almost the exact same and the controller is in the parent view's controller)?

Comment: If so, what should the "get" look like in this case? (also how can I find out then name of the parent controller from the REPL in chrome if I pause it here w/ the debugger statement) ?

Comment: I just saw you were extending text field, here's my implementation that the controller is the controller in scope.  text field is a component, so it's essentially a liar when it says view, so you can't get the controller etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TextField is a component, so the parent controller doesn't exist, you'd need to use `sendAction` to get things out of it.

Here's my implementation of the upload button that's just a view.

```
App.UploadFileView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'input',
  attributeBindings: ['type'],
  type: 'file',
  change: function() {
    console.log(this.get('controller'));
  }  
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/oQaReMi/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an Ember Component (like TextField for example) you would do this like so

```
App.UploadFileView = Ember.TextField.extend({
  change: function() {
    console.log(this.get('targetObject'));
  }  
});
```

Note- this is in the current version of ember 1.3.x